# Eager loading with many to many relationship in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to set up at messaging system in laravel 4. I have two classes Conversation and User with a many to many relationship between them. I'm outputting a list of a logged in user's conversations and the users in the conversations:

```
@foreach(User::find(Auth::user()->id)->conversations as $conversation) 

    {{ $conversation->id }}

    @foreach($conversation->users as $user) 
        {{ $user->name }}
    @endforeach   

    <br><br>

@endforeach
```

This is working and outputs the conversation id followed by the name of the users participating in that conversation. My problem is that this way a lot of queries are run and I can't figure out how to use eager loading and still be able to select only the logged in users conversations. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:

With the following code I get the right output, but still queries the database a lot:

```
<?php $user = User::with('conversations')->find(Auth::user()->id); ?>

{{ $user->username }}'s conversations<br><br>
@foreach($user->conversations as $conversation) 
    {{ $conversation->id }} 
    @foreach($conversation->users as $user) 
        {{ $user->name }}
    @endforeach
    <br>
@endforeach
```

I would really like to be able to eager load this part @foreach($conversation->users as $user). It outputs:

user_1's conversations

1 user_1 user_2

5 user_1 user_3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe at any instance there will be only 1 user session active. Why do you need foreach to loop over `logged in` users? How is your application working?

To eager load:

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

$conversations = $user::with('conversation')->get();
```

Or as pointed out by @David Barker :

```
User::with('conversation')->find(Auth::user()->id)
```

A conversation may belong to many users. So:

```
$conversation_id = [];

@foreach($user->conversations as $conversation) 
    array_push($conversation_id, $conversation->id);
@endforeach

$conversations_with_users = Conversation::with('user')->whereIn('id', $conversation_id);
```

now loop over the $conversations_with_users.

Comment: That still runs two queries on user. `User::with('conversations')->find(Auth::user()->id);` would be more efficient as long as the Auth user is cached. Otherwise extending Auth to always eager load conversations would be better.

Comment: @Lucky Soni : Yes there is only one active user, but I need to loop over that user's conversations. And then again loop over the users for each conversation. I edited my question after trying your solution. Hope you can help so I can mark as solved.

Comment: @Lucky Soni Thanks for the update, this is working for me, will mark as solved :)